# How to upgrade MongoDB on Windows Server

Tags: windows, mongodb, upgrade

How do you upgrade MongoDB on Windows server? Running the Windows installer for the new version only installs a new copy of MongoDB and ignores the existing copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**
First start the cmd.exe in admin mode and cd to the location of the old installation, for standard installations:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
```

Stop all applications, which are accessing mongodb, then enter

```
mongod --remove
```

Then install the new mongo db, copy the mongod.cfg file from 3.2 to 3.4 directory. When you had one, otherwise follow the [installation instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition) for setting up the new service. This update worked fine for me, all data available, I didn't need to use [this features switched off](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-standalone/#upgrade-process).

Comment: I have read that document and it's target audience is Linux, not Windows.

Comment: I'm doing the update right now on a separate machine, because I'm curious, I will update the answer soon.

Comment: Updatet, the old code is inactive afterwards, I didn't removed it.

Comment: I guess the issue is how we define "upgrade". We are effectively installing a new version and pointing it to our existing data, which I guess you can call an upgrade. If you are dealing with an msi usually the package upgrades existing files. This is just install new application, point at old data. /end rant. Thanks for your help though, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded from version 3.6.0 to 3.6.2 just today and below are the steps involved:

1. Download the latest version from the [mongodb wesbite][1].
2. When downloading is complete, stop any running instance of mongodb by typing 'Ctrl+C' on the command console.
3. Run the installation file and it automatically installs the new version at the same path as the previous version (at C:\Program
   Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6).
4. Start the database server by typing 'mongod'.
5. All previous databases will be accessible to you.

Comment: This worked for me and all my collections where intact

Answer (score 0):

Windows MongoDB major version upgrade can be performed easily `in-place` , here i am describing the steps to upgrade **MongoDB 4.2 to 4.4** with existing data directory. You can follow the same for any version upgrade.

We will use the `Windows command prompt` to perform all steps below:

1. For safety take a backup of existing DB, provide a path to backup them

> cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin

> mongodump -o D:\DB_backup

2. Stop all the application writes and shutdown the MongoDB service

> type "services. msc" and hit Enter or press OK

> Services -> MongoDB Server -> Right click & stop

3. Install the new MongoDB **mongodb-windows-x86_64-enterprise-4.4.8-signed.msi file** msi package by using GUI provide the old exixting directories. Meanwhile rename directory from 4.2 to 4.4

> Data dir - D:\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data

> ```
> Log dir  - D:\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\
> ```

This will replace all the bin files with older version ones and MongoDB will be started automatically.

4. Finally , move to the bin directory, run **mongo.exe** client and check the DB availablity

> cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin

Answer (score 0):

**On windows pro.**

It worked for me like below:

1. Install new version without uninstalling existing.
2. Stop the mongodb service.
3. Copy data folder from previous mongo to new mongo folder.
4. Repair new mongo installation.
5. Uninstall previous mongodb.